# Blackberry Bitmapfield taking space on screen but not showing in horizontalfieldmanager

Tags: blackberry, bitmapfield

I am using this code -

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    this.add(hfm);
Bitmap HELLO_LOGO = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("test.jpg");
BitmapField helloBmpField = new BitmapField(HELLO_LOGO);
hfm.add(helloBmpField);
```

I have 3 files in the img folder under res - test.jpg,icon.png,tester.gif
I also have a labelfield in the horizontal manager.
Either of them show now but not both. I have checked the size of the image that is fine too.
I have tried all 3 files one by one - it takes up some space on the screen but the image doesn't show up with any of the 3 files

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: I've used the same code you posted above, just changed the image name `"test.jpg"` to an image in the `res/img/test.jpg` of my project folder, and added the code in the constructor of my `MainScreen`... it's working fine On 9700 (OS_5), 9800 (OS_6) and 9300 (OS_7) simulators. Don't understand why you are facing problem... Provide us with some more code... at least your whole `MainScreen` where you've added the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some debug output statements to this code, and check if the image is loaded.

Missing some context, I assume this code is taken from the constructor of a Screen class. If not, this could be a problem with the event-handling thread.

First check: is the filename comlete? should it be "img/test.jpg" instead of "test.jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the **`extension`** of the name of the image you have put in your **`res`** folder. May be the image is named as **`test.JPG`** (capital letter for extension) in the **`res`** folder but in your code you've written **`test.jpg`** (small letter for extension)   or any other naming mistake like this...